# .NET Azure sdk resource manager - NuGet package: Stable release

Tags: .net, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I'm planning to handle some Azure ARM code in .NET 6 and want to use Azure libraries.

I found that there are 2 NuGet packages (old and new) available:

1. Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent

Ref:
[NuGet Gallery | Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent 1.38.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent)
NuGet doc says that "This package is in low maintenance mode and being phased out. To use the latest Azure SDK for resource management, please see [https://aka.ms/azsdk/dotnet/mgmt"](https://aka.ms/azsdk/dotnet/mgmt%22). This means that it package will not be supported in near future.

2. Azure.ResourceManager

Ref: [NuGet Gallery | Azure.ResourceManager 1.0.0-beta.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager/1.0.0-beta.8)
The official doc https://aka.ms/azsdk/dotnet/mgmt (referred from above
NuGet suggestion) says that "Azure.ResourceManager.* packages are
currently in Public Preview and may be subject to breaking changes in
the future."

The former one is about to get deprecated and the latter one is still in beta release mode. Which package should be considered to be use for long term support application development. This needs to be used on production, so would going for beta release package recommended?
Any expected stable release date for Azure.ResourceManager.* libraries?

Comment: So you'll either have to rewrite your code when the old package goes out of service, or rewrite your code if the new package has a breaking change between Beta 8 and release. The real difference is that bugs in the old package won't get fixed, precisely because it's in "low maintenance mode".

Comment: There's no easy answer to this. Long term, you should use the new package, especially as the old one won't get any fixes. You can't guess how long it will be until a stable release though. Are you OK with redeploying every month when a new Beta comes out?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's a short operation worth 2-3 month of development timeline. But if cumulative maintenance timeline (including multiple upgrades to stable releases) exceeds the development timeline, it won't be worth starting development now.

Comment: You can check the release notes for the new package [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager_1.0.0-beta.8/sdk/resourcemanager/Azure.ResourceManager/CHANGELOG.md). Beta 8 introduced quite a few breaking changes, so it seems the project is still in flux. Only you can answer your question, because only you know the actual time requirements. We can't guess the release timeline, so we can't guess what will change.

Comment: You can check the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/resourcemanager/Azure.ResourceManager/docs/MigrationGuide.md) to get an idea what it would take to migrate from the old package to the new one. You should probably design your code so it's easy to switch from one package to the other, and budget some time to migrate to the new package when it's released.

Comment: Thanks for Migration Guide @PanagiotisKanavos. This helped to foresee the expected changes.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure SDK for .net has GAed 2 key libraries https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager/ and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources/
Other azure services' SDK for .net will be available soon, we strongly recommend you start with the new version of Azure .NET SDK which start with name space Azure.Resource
Meanwhile we are looking forward to hear our customer's feedback of the SDK experience, don't hesitate to raise your issue in our azure sdk .net github repo or directly reaching out to us via email

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see that now the stable release is available.